# How I must save money transaction in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have wallet and business concepts in my project and it's possible to transfer money between wallet and business and between businesses.

I have a table for wallet transactions and if I have a money transfer from the wallet to business or business to wallet, I'll save it in the `wallet_transactions` table.

Also I have a table for business transactions and if I have a money transfer between businesses I'll save it in the `business_transactions` table.

Now I need to fetch all of the transactions regarding to a business and display them descending in a table with pagination

Must I save a money transform from the wallet to business or business to wallet in the `business_transactions` table or I must use the join?

Comment: The line of least resistance seems to be use a union (ie a vertical join) - before displaying.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks :)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.